# In which directory do files get downloaded when using download_data command in gae

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata to download data from google app engine. The data gets successfully downloaded (per the python output) but I am not able to find the file on the filesystem.

E.g., For the following command, I get success but I can't find bulkloader.yaml in my computer. I have tried microsoft (Win 7) inbuilt search, google-desktop search, but I get 0 results. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine>python appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://appname.appspot.com/remote_api

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all worked, the file should be in the same directory from which you started the command appcfg.py. the default directory of command prompt windows is something like C:\Documents and Settings\User. Try to take a look there or restart command from a directory of your choice.

edit: in your case the file is probably in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine

Comment: Appreciate your response. Unfortunately, I don't see any file named bulkloader.yaml in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine. Even after search I am not able to find it. (have spent almost whole day on this).